# How filter through XML response from CURL HTTP POST Request

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap

Response from CURL request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:header>
      <soap-env:body>
         <ipgapi:ipgapiorderresponse xmlns:ipgapi="http://ipg-online.com/ipgapi/schemas/ipgapi" xmlns:a1="http://ipg-online.com/ipgapi/schemas/a1" xmlns:v1="http://ipg-online.com/ipgapi/schemas/v1">
            <ipgapi:approvalcode>Y:761862:4515799310:PPXP:0037</ipgapi:approvalcode>
            <ipgapi:avsresponse>PPX</ipgapi:avsresponse>
            <ipgapi:brand>VISA</ipgapi:brand>
            <ipgapi:country>GBR</ipgapi:country>
            <ipgapi:commercialserviceprovider>BOSMS</ipgapi:commercialserviceprovider>
            <ipgapi:orderid>A-966025d3-81a2-453a-820e-bb145e8390d1</ipgapi:orderid>
            <ipgapi:ipgtransactionid>84515799310</ipgapi:ipgtransactionid>
            <ipgapi:paymenttype>CREDITCARD</ipgapi:paymenttype>
            <ipgapi:processorapprovalcode>761862</ipgapi:processorapprovalcode>
            <ipgapi:processorccvresponse>P</ipgapi:processorccvresponse>
            <ipgapi:processorreferencenumber>761862</ipgapi:processorreferencenumber>
            <ipgapi:processorresponsecode>00</ipgapi:processorresponsecode>
            <ipgapi:processorresponsemessage>AUTH CODE:761862</ipgapi:processorresponsemessage>
            <ipgapi:tdate>1521047872</ipgapi:tdate>
            <ipgapi:tdateformatted>2018.03.14 18:17:52 (CET)</ipgapi:tdateformatted>
            <ipgapi:terminalid>21400371</ipgapi:terminalid>
            <ipgapi:transactionresult>APPROVED</ipgapi:transactionresult>
            <ipgapi:transactiontime>1521047872</ipgapi:transactiontime>
         </ipgapi:ipgapiorderresponse>
      </soap-env:body>
   </soap-env:header>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

I've tried the following:

```
$responseXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:header>
      <soap-env:body>
         <ipgapi:ipgapiorderresponse xmlns:ipgapi="http://ipg-online.com/ipgapi/schemas/ipgapi" xmlns:a1="http://ipg-online.com/ipgapi/schemas/a1" xmlns:v1="http://ipg-online.com/ipgapi/schemas/v1">
            <ipgapi:approvalcode>Y:761862:4515799310:PPXP:0037</ipgapi:approvalcode>
            <ipgapi:avsresponse>PPX</ipgapi:avsresponse>
            <ipgapi:brand>VISA</ipgapi:brand>
            <ipgapi:country>GBR</ipgapi:country>
            <ipgapi:commercialserviceprovider>BOSMS</ipgapi:commercialserviceprovider>
            <ipgapi:orderid>A-966025d3-81a2-453a-820e-bb145e8390d1</ipgapi:orderid>
            <ipgapi:ipgtransactionid>84515799310</ipgapi:ipgtransactionid>
            <ipgapi:paymenttype>CREDITCARD</ipgapi:paymenttype>
            <ipgapi:processorapprovalcode>761862</ipgapi:processorapprovalcode>
            <ipgapi:processorccvresponse>P</ipgapi:processorccvresponse>
            <ipgapi:processorreferencenumber>761862</ipgapi:processorreferencenumber>
            <ipgapi:processorresponsecode>00</ipgapi:processorresponsecode>
            <ipgapi:processorresponsemessage>AUTH CODE:761862</ipgapi:processorresponsemessage>
            <ipgapi:tdate>1521047872</ipgapi:tdate>
            <ipgapi:tdateformatted>2018.03.14 18:17:52 (CET)</ipgapi:tdateformatted>
            <ipgapi:terminalid>21400371</ipgapi:terminalid>
            <ipgapi:transactionresult>APPROVED</ipgapi:transactionresult>
            <ipgapi:transactiontime>1521047872</ipgapi:transactiontime>
         </ipgapi:ipgapiorderresponse>
      </soap-env:body>
   </soap-env:header>
</soap-env:envelope>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($responseXML);
print_r($xml);
// Returns empty object
```

I've also tried the following:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($responseXML);
print_r($xml);
// This also returns empty object
```

Could someone help me figure out what's going wrong with this?

Comment: Double and single quote Chris. basic stuff, just look at the code highlighting

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Sorry my bad, I press submit without fixing the single quotes

Comment: [From the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php): This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `print_r();` with a SimpleXMLElement usually doesn't give anything useful.  Instead you should use `asXML()` which outputs the original XML.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($responseXML);
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Which gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:header>
      <soap-env:body>
...
```

You can access the data by using something like...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($responseXML);
$body = $xml->xpath("//soap-env:body");
$bodyData = $body[0]->children("ipgapi", true);
echo $bodyData->ipgapiorderresponse->approvalcode;
```

So `$bodyData` is the `<ipgapi:ipgapiorderresponse ...>` element and so accessing each part of that is by using the last line.  You can use the element name (minus the namespace prefix ipgapi as this is taken care of with the `children()` call earlier).  That line outputs

```
Y:761862:4515799310:PPXP:0037
```

Comment: Then how do I get the individual values in the XML?

Comment: Hello the accessing the data doesn't work like that. The first example of $xml->asXML() worked though.